# How to implement a callback that could receive any parameters and return any values?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

In c#, I want to design a pattern that the user register a callback:

```
    Pseudocode：
    RegisterCallBack(function, String key)
```

like this and I can call it runtime according to the key given like:

```
    callfunc(key)
```

then the function can be called. I hope this function could be any functions that receive any parameters and return any values.

So could anyone tell me how to implement this?

Comment: If you're initiating calling it with `callfunc(key)`, where would the parameters come from? And where would the return value be returned to? As the return value of `callfunc`?

Comment: Params - look it up https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228391(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depends on when you invoke the callback, do you expect something as return or just fire and forget. If just fire and forget then

```
RegisterCallback( Action<String> callback, String key) { ... }
```

If you expect, say an int, as a return value then

```
RegisterCallback(Func<String, int> callback, String key) { ... }
```

You can invoke simply as `var p = callback(key);`

For *any* number of parameters, it wont be so clean. All of the parameters will have to be of the same type.

```
RegisterCallback(Action<String[]> callback, params String[] keys)
```

Then call it as `callback(keys);`. But while registering the callback, the client code needs to be something like this.

```
void myCallBack(String[] keys){ ... }

foo.RegisterCallback(myCallBack, "bar", "baz");
```

Note that the `myCallBack` implementation does not have nicely named parameters. I cannot tjink of any way to have both named parameters in callback implementation *and* any number of parameters.

Comment: Using Func has a limited amount of parameters

Answer (score 0):

Since any delegate can be casted to `Delegate`, nothing prevents from doing this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public class CallbackArgs1
    {
        public CallbackArgs1(string text)
        {
            Text = text;
        }

        public string Text { get; }
    }

    public class CallbackArgs2
    {
        public CallbackArgs2(int number)
        {
            Number = number;
        }

        public int Number { get; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // #1 You build a callback list with two sample callbacks
        List<Delegate> callbacks = new List<Delegate>();
        callbacks.Add(new Func<CallbackArgs1, int>(args => args.Text.Length));
        callbacks.Add(new Func<CallbackArgs2, string>(args => args.Number.ToString()));

        // This list will store each callback result
        List<object> callbackResults = new List<object>();

        foreach(Delegate callback in callbacks)
        {
            // #2 This gets first Func<T, TResult> generic argument
            // which is the argument class type
            Type argsType = callback.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

            // #3 Now it's about checking the arguments class type
            // and instantiate it 
            object args;

            if(typeof(CallbackArgs1).IsAssignableFrom(argsType))
            {
                args = new CallbackArgs1("hello world");
            }
            else if(typeof(CallbackArgs2).IsAssignableFrom(argsType))
            {
                args = new CallbackArgs2(282);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            // #4 Finally, the callback is dynamically called passing
            // the arguments class instance and the return value is 
            // stored in the callback result list.
            callbackResults.Add(callback.DynamicInvoke(new [] { args }));
        }


        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", callbackResults.Select(r => r.ToString())));
    }
}
```

That is, you can build a callback list of concrete delegates casted to `Delegate` and dynamically-invoke them all, passing the proper arguments inspecting the first `Func<>` parameter type.

Therefore, the convention is that you must use `Func<T, TResult>`, where `T` will be a class of arguments like the ones in the code snippet, and `TResult` can be whatever, either reference or value types.

Anyway, I'm unsure about if this will work for you, because you'll need to work on some way to decide what arguments you provide to particular arguments classes instead of how I did in the code snippet, where I've hardcoded them...